# Cartoon identification: Two kids in a ship full of robots

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I'm trying to find a cartoon I saw a few minutes of when I was young. It was on UK children's TV, probably between 1988 and 1992. I remember two kids, a boy and a girl, and there were some kind of ships floating in the sky. They managed to get on the ships and there were lots of robots on them, but they were all deactivated. The girl said something about her father making the robots.

Unfortunately that's about all I saw, but I've always wondered what it was. Any ideas?

Comment: "*Ships floating in the sky*" = **[sailing](http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2395/2619011154_0cf8223619_o.jpg)** ships?

Comment: @Richard No, I was thinking they were more like spaceships, though in the few minutes I saw there wasn't any indication they actually travelled through space.

Comment: Cylindrical? Fins? Also, can you describe the robots? How did they get onto the ships? What age were the boy and the girl? Was this Western or Japanese style animation? Do you remember their names?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animated_television_series_of_the_1980s

Comment: @Richard Unfortunately I saw so little of it before my sister changed the channel I can't really provide more detail. I'd say it was Japanese style though.

Answer (score 8):

The description provided sounds a lot like [Laputa: Castle in the Sky (1986)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_in_the_Sky), directed by [Hayao Miyazaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayao_Miyazaki)

[image]

There are the two protagonists, the Pazu and Lucita Toel Ur Laputa (Sheeta)

They are in a Japanese/Victorian/steampunk setting, where airships are used.

[image]
[image]

They end up on the Castle in the Sky, where the civilization had collapsed, leaving their robots, most of which eventually broke down. There was a scene showing hundreds of robots just sliding out of their holding tubes to their destruction because they were had long since broken, but I cannot find the image.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Certainly possible. I'll see if I can watch it and see if it's the one. Thanks.

Comment: Just watched it, and it's a great film. Unfortunately despite sounding promising I'm 99% sure it wasn't what I remembered. The general plot could feasibly fit though, so might there have been another show / film based on the same story?

Answer (score 4):

I found it, i was looking for it too. It is called: Skyland
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/Skyland
Episode 1
http://www.toonova.com/skyland-episode-1
I hope that this is what you were looking for

Comment: I was so excited to see your post, but alas from that first link it sounds like it was first shown in 2005, where as I definitely saw this before 2000. I'll check out the episode though and confirm.

Comment: If it isn't, i hope you will find it someday

Answer (score 1):

1979
***Little Orbit the Astrodog and the Screechers from Outer Space***??

Comment: _"Video unavailable This video contains content from W4tch TV, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds"_ 

Could you add more details as to why it is the correct one?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've only had a chance to skim through that video and the drawing style doesn't seem to be anything like I remember, so I don't think this is it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details you provided, it could be the animated series "**[Ulysses 31](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1732)**".

It was a French-Japanese co-production that aired in the UK during the late 80s, and followed the adventures of Ulysses and his companions, including a boy and girl, as they traveled through space on a quest to find their way back home to Earth. They encounter many strange ships and creatures along the way, including robots, some of which are deactivated.

I'm not certain about the specific detail of the girl's father making the robots, but it's possible it could be a part of the story.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on this, very excited that 8 years after posting my question I'm getting more suggestions! Looks like I might have to watch this series to see if it is the one. From a quick look at some videos on YouTube I'd say it's not what I'm looking for, but since I only watched a few minutes of it 30 years ago or so it's hard to say. My memory has probably been tainted by lots of other things since then, but I'd say the colours were more drab than this.